# How to identify client's timezone in NodeJS from server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, momentjs

I am saving the time in mongodb database in UTC format. But I want to display the time to client, according to their timezone. Currently the time is being displayed according to the server's timezone. I can change server's timezone to some other value but then it would be again static and not display according to client's timezone.

I tried using getTimezoneOffset() but it shows 0 offset and MomentJS guess function shows UTC timezone even when client's timezone is Asia Pacific.
So how to get timezone or offset of client and not according to the server location using NodeJS at backend?

Comment: send the time to the browser in UTC ... then let the browser display whatever the client wants - of course, without a single line of code, that's about as much help as you'll get - example ... send `1554625232340` ... then `new Date(1554625232340)` on the client side will be able to display in their timezone

Comment: I am using templating engine to render the page, so I have to manipulate the date before it reaches browser. If that's not possible then I was thinking about two solutions: 1. Storing the user's timezone in session using their IP address 2. Assigning class to each time attribute at frontend and then manipulating it in browser using the solution you suggested   ... So which is the preferred way according to you?

Comment: `so I have to manipulate the date before it reaches browser` no, let the browser manipulate the date

Comment: Ok thank you. You made it much simpler, at server side this would have got very complicated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [request-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip) and [geoip-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geoip-lite). requestIp will give you the ip of client and when You pass that ip to geoip it will give you various info which includes timezone. You can then use that timezone with moment to convert your utc date to that timezone date.